# Interaction between JS and API server on different port

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain-policy

I have an API server running on port `AAAA` and the JS frontend app (emberjs, using yeoman) running on port `BBBB` on the development machine. On the live server these ports will be the same. Unfortunately on the development machine I run into cross origin policy problems.

What can I do about this?

PS: Currently I solved this by starting Chrome using

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
```

and using an absolute root path `http://localhost:8888/` in the JS api. But I'm not really a fan of hardcoded urls and special flags. If there is a better solution for either, please let me know!

Comment: Assuming you can't change the development environment, you could test with a browser that lets you relax (or remove) cross domain policies. (Chrome allows this via command line switches.) But I think it would be better to try to have the dev environment reflect the production environment.

Comment: Yes, I did it that way using chrome - but the approach is fragile since I have to use a hardcoded url for the port.

Comment: It would be nice if you could forward any request that causes a 404 to another port. That way you can use relative urls assuming requests made to the api would not be there.

Comment: CORS is very useful for these types of situations, provided you have configuration-access to the server: http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using chrome with `--disable-web-security`, I used this snippet to avoid hardcoding the API origin

```
var origin = location.origin.replace(/localhost:(\d+)/, 'localhost:8888');
```

and only change it for local development.